# Display Parent Records After Related Child Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
declare @t1 table
(Id int,
Name nvarchar(200)
)

declare @t2 table
(Id int,
t1Id int fk,
Name nvarchar(200),
Amount decimal(18,2)
)

declare @t3 table
(
t2Id int,
t1Id int,
Name nvarchar(200),
total decimal(18,2)
)

insert into @t1 values (1, 'Technology')
insert into @t1 values (2, 'Database')
insert into @t1 values (3, 'ABC')

insert into @t2 values (1, 1, '.Net', 10)
insert into @t2 values (2, 1, 'PHP', 10)
insert into @t2 values (3, 1, 'Python', 10)
insert into @t2 values (4, 2, 'SQL', 20)
insert into @t2 values (5, 2, 'MySQL', 30)
insert into @t2 values (6, 3, 'JKL', 10)
insert into @t2 values (7, 3, 'PQR', 40)

insert into @t3 values (1, 1, '.Net', 10)
insert into @t3 values (2, 1, 'PHP', 10)
insert into @t3 values (3, 1, 'Python', 10)
insert into @t3 values (null, 1, 'Technology', 30)
insert into @t3 values (4, 2, 'SQL', 20)
insert into @t3 values (5, 2, 'MySQL', 30)
insert into @t3 values (null, 2, 'Database', 50)
insert into @t3 values (6, 3, 'JKL', 10)
insert into @t3 values (7, 3, 'PQR', 40)
insert into @t3 values (null, 3, 'ABC', 50)
```

I have two tables in SQL which is @t1 and @t2 and I expect @t3 table as output.
How to achieve this?

desired output is table @t3.

Comment: FYI SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support *4 years* ago. It is *long* past time you implemented your finalised upgrade path by now.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Create table @t1
declare @t1 table
(
    Id int,
    Name nvarchar(200)
)

-- Create table @t2
declare @t2 table
(
    Id int,
    t1Id int,
    Name nvarchar(200),
    Amount decimal(18,2)
)

-- Create table @t3
declare @t3 table
(
    t2Id int,
    t1Id int,
    Name nvarchar(200),
    total decimal(18,2)
)

-- Insert data into @t1
insert into @t1 values (1, 'Technology')
insert into @t1 values (2, 'Database')
insert into @t1 values (3, 'ABC')

-- Insert data into @t2
insert into @t2 values (1, 1, '.Net', 10)
insert into @t2 values (2, 1, 'PHP', 10)
insert into @t2 values (3, 1, 'Python', 10)
insert into @t2 values (4, 2, 'SQL', 20)
insert into @t2 values (5, 2, 'MySQL', 30)
insert into @t2 values (6, 3, 'JKL', 10)
insert into @t2 values (7, 3, 'PQR', 40)


select * from @t3  
-- Insert data into @t3 and calculate the totals
insert into @t3
select
    t2.Id as t2Id,
    t1.Id as t1Id,
    t2.Name,
    t2.Amount as total
from @t1 t1
inner join @t2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.t1Id

-- Calculate the totals for each group in @t2 and update @t3
update t3
set t3.total = t2.Amount
from @t3 t3
inner join (
    select t1Id, sum(Amount) as Amount
    from @t2
    group by t1Id
) t2 on t3.t1Id = t2.t1Id
where t3.t2Id is null
select * from @t3
```

| t2Id | t1Id | Name | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

| t2Id | t1Id | Name | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | .Net | 10.00 |
| 2 | 1 | PHP | 10.00 |
| 3 | 1 | Python | 10.00 |
| 4 | 2 | SQL | 20.00 |
| 5 | 2 | MySQL | 30.00 |
| 6 | 3 | JKL | 10.00 |
| 7 | 3 | PQR | 40.00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rCWfzs2i)

Comment: That doesn't get the expected results...

Comment: I want parent record under child records like under 'Python' it will come 'Technology', under 'MySQL' it will come 'Database' so @t3 table will have 10 records

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `union all` and a common table expression:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 0 As IsT1,
       Id As t2Id,
       t1Id,
       Name, 
      Amount As total
FROM @t2

UNION ALL

SELECT 1 As IsT1,
       NULL,
       T1.Id,
       T1.NAME,
       SUM(Amount)
FROM @t1 As T1
JOIN @t2 AS T2
   ON T1.Id = T2.T1Id
GROUP BY T1.Id, T1.Name
)
  
SELECT t2Id, t1Id, Name, total
FROM CTE
ORDER BY t1Id, IsT1, t2Id
```

Results:

```
t2Id    t1Id    Name        total
1       1       .Net        10.00
2       1       PHP         10.00
3       1       Python      10.00
null    1       Technology  30.00
4       2       SQL         20.00
5       2       MySQL       30.00
null    2       Database    50.00
6       3       JKL         10.00
7       3       PQR         40.00
null    3       ABC         50.00
```

Comment: @DaleK Yes, but then you have an extra column in your select clause. You can't use a `case` expression in the `order by` of the `union`  query because you'll get an error - "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator." [See fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/P2EWFs6Z)

Comment: @DaleK because I don't need it since I'm using a cte I can hard code the values into the different queries in the union... Without a cte, I would have to either add these hard coded values to the output, or use `case` (or another expression-based solution) to get the values in the correct order.